# Burmese font in Android

Tags: android, string, unicode, locale

We have existing Android application, now we are planning to add language support for Myanmar(Burmese). We just realized that Burmese script can be written in 2 ways

1. Zawgyi
2. Unicode

But we can have either one of the string inside **values-my** folder. So right now our Android app has Zawgyi strings inside **values-my** folder. It is works fine if user device locale is Burmese(Zawgyi), but it doesn't looks good if user's device locale is Burmese(Unicode).

When search in internet, people suggest to use converter to display Unicode string in Zawgyi. But our application have 1000+ TextViews, so we are really concerned about application performance and don't want to use conversion.

1. Is it possible to display default string, if user locale setting is Burmese Unicode?
2. Is there any other efficient way to display Burmese strings?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, Did you got a solution for this? Please share your solution as I am also in the same issue.

Comment: Oh...not really. We decided to support only Zawgyi users. If we found a unicode user, we just blocking them at splash screen. 
Because we don't want to use converter.

Between, it is up to you decide what you really want.